# Generate test database with Phoenix espec

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm considering migrating my Elixir/Phoenix project tests from ExUnit to [espec_phoenix](https://github.com/antonmi/espec_phoenix).

When I have a test database set up before running the tests, it's working as expected.

But when I don't, I get an error:

> 12:04:27.581 [error] Postgrex.Protocol (#PID<0.433.0>) failed to
>   connect: ** (Postgrex.Error) FATAL 3D000 (invalid_catalog_name):
>   database "my_project_test" does not exist

I'd like espec_phoenix to set the DB up for me, just as ExUnit did.

Any ideas how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ExUnit` did not do anything with a database. This is `mix`’s alias who did:

```
defp aliases do
  [
    ...
    "test": ["ecto.create --quiet", "ecto.migrate", "test"]
  ]
end
```

I believe `espec_phoenix` uses different task name, so, just alias it as following:

```
    #            or how the original task is called  ⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓
    "espec": ["ecto.create --quiet", "ecto.migrate", "espec"]
```